# How to overwrite existing dotenv entry with new value

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I am trying to read, then overwrite an existing dotenv entry. How do I access it by parsed key name then update it?

```js
const env = require('dotenv').config()

let envVar = 'MY_VAR'
let envExists = false

if(!env.error) envExists = Object.keys(env.parsed).includes(envVar)

if(envExists === true){
  process.env[envVar] = 'something else'
}
```

Comment: Will you use the env somewhere else in your code ? I think it's easy to use a `let myVar = Object.keys(env.parsed).includes(envVar) ? process.env[envVar] : 'something else'`

Comment: You know what? I just realized I actually was successfully updating it -- in memory. I want to be able to update the file...